# VBA: Usar o Excel para renomear arquivos em uma pasta

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou pensando em usar o Visual Basic do Excel para padronizar o nome de 6000 arquivos em uma determinada pasta. Estes arquivos estão misturados entre fotos e documentos, portanto há uma variedade de extensões (DOC, DOCX, PDF, TIF, TIFF, JPG, JPGEm BMP, PNG, MSG...).

Minha intenção seria passar pela pasta e tornar todos os nomes dos arquivos em letras maiúsculas e a extensão em letra minúscula, como no exemplo:

- `paramentro contabil.PDF` será renomeado como `PARAMETRO CONTABIL.pdf`
- `OPPO - finacials.tif` será renomeado como `OPPO - FINANCIALS.tif`

Imagino que eu teria que utilizar um loop `For Each Next` para executar o código, mas não sei como dimensionar as variáveis e se há alguma função especial para renomear arquivos fora do Excel.

O que estou querendo fazer é possivel?

Comment: Os nomes dos arquivos já estão na planilha ou sua macro teria que ler os arquivos da pasta também?

Comment: Não, os nomes não estão na planilha e eu nem pretendia copiá-los lá. Minha ideia era renomear os arquivos diretamente na pasta, apenas usando a VBA para executar o código, sem usar a planilha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue abaixo código que aplica o que vc quer para todos os arquivos de uma determinada pasta, independente da extensão, ignorando subpastas:

```
Sub Renomear()

'Dimensionar variáveis
    Dim MyFolder, MyFile, NewName As String, i As Integer
        MyFolder = "H:\My Documents\Certificates\"
        MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.*")

'Passar por cada arquivo na pasta e executar ação
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        i = InStr(1, MyFile, ".", 1)
        NewName = UCase(Left(MyFile, i)) & LCase(Right(MyFile, Len(MyFile) - i))
        Name MyFolder & MyFile As MyFolder & NewName
        MyFile = Dir
        Loop

End Sub
```

A linha chave para definir como o novo nome vai ficar é essa:

```
NewName = UCase(Left(MyFile, i)) & LCase(Right(MyFile, Len(MyFile) - i))
```

Caso vc queira modificar como o arquivo deve ficarm bastar manipular essa linha. Por exemplo, caso queira que tudo fique em letra maiúscula, pasta escrever `NewName = UCase(MyFile)`. E, conforme adicionado por vc nos comentários, esse código só utiliza a VBA para ser executado mas nem chega a utilizar o Excel em si.

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que:

- Um arquivo por linha
- Somente um ponto no nome do arquivo (o ponto que separa a extensão do nome do arquivo)

---

Rode a seguinte macro para listar todos os arquivos de um diretório nas células da coluna A da planilha.

**Código1:**

```
Sub lista_arquivos()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    'cria uma instancia do FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'pega o objeto
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\User-1\Desktop\")
    i = 1

    'loop em cada arquivo da pasta
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        'salva nome do arquivo na linha i+1, coluna A
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name

        i = i + 1

    Next objFile

End Sub
```

---

E após isso, rode a seguinte macro para alterar o nome dos arquivos:

**Código2:**

```
Sub renomear_arqs()

    'para todas as celulas não vazias da coluna A, faça o seguinte:
    For i = 1 To Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
        'pega nome original do arquivo
        arq_antigo = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)

        'procura ponto no nome do arquivo
        pos_ponto = WorksheetFunction.Find(".", arq_antigo)

        'coloca maiusculo tudo à esquerda do ponto
        esq_arq_novo = UCase(Left(arq_antigo, pos_ponto))

        'coloca minusculo tudo à direita do ponto
        dir_arq_novo = LCase(Right(arq_antigo, Len(arq_antigo) - pos_ponto))

        'une a parte a esquerda com a parte a direita
        arq_novo = esq_arq_novo + dir_arq_novo

        'cola o nome novo na mesma linha do arq em questão, na coluna B
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = arq_novo

        'renomeia os arquivos
        Name arq_antigo As arq_novo

    'pula pra proxima linha, que deve conter o nome do outro arquivo..
    Next

End Sub
```

---

**Imagem Exemplo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

```
Name "Caminho\nome do arquivo.pdf" as "Caminho\nomedoarquivo.pdf"
```

Ai é só usar variáveis e adaptar a seu código.